# How to implement variable increment via side effect?

Tags: rust, side-effects

For learning purposes, I tried this solution, but [it does not work](http://is.gd/NHY03w):

```
use std::ops::Add;

fn inc<T: Add>(x:&mut T) {
    *x += 1; 
}

fn main() {
    let mut x:i32 = 10;
    let mut y:u8 = 1;
    inc(&mut x);
    inc(&mut y);
    println!("{} {}", x, y);
}
```

Error message:

```
<anon>:4:5: 4:7 error: binary assignment operation `+=` cannot be applied to types `T` and `_` [E0368]
<anon>:4     *x += 1; 
             ^~
<anon>:4:5: 4:7 help: see the detailed explanation for E0368
error: aborting due to previous error
```

What is the right way to do that?

Comment: The detailed explanation is missing in stable Rust, but available in the nightly channel: https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/error-index.html#E0368

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At present, `+=` is only defined on the primitive integer types; generically, you will need to expand it to `*x = *x + 1;` instead. This then reveals more problems:

```
<anon>:4:15: 4:16 error: mismatched types:
 expected `T`,
    found `_`
(expected type parameter,
    found integral variable) [E0308]
<anon>:4     *x = *x + 1; 
                       ^
<anon>:4:10: 4:16 error: mismatched types:
 expected `T`,
    found `<T as core::ops::Add>::Output`
(expected type parameter,
    found associated type) [E0308]
<anon>:4     *x = *x + 1; 
                  ^~~~~~
error: aborting due to 2 previous errors
```

Let’s look at the `Add` trait’s definition:

```rust
pub trait Add<RHS = Self> {
    /// The resulting type after applying the `+` operator
    type Output;

    /// The method for the `+` operator
    fn add(self, rhs: RHS) -> Self::Output;
}
```

So `Self + RHS` produces an object of type `<Self as Add<RHS>>::Output`.

As you’re storing the value back in `*x`, the result of the calculation must be a `T`; thus we establish that the bound on `T` will need to be not `Add` but `Add<???, Output = T>`.

What, then, will `???` be? What is the type of `1`? It’s not generic; it’s one of the ten known primitive integer types (`isize`, `i8`, `i16`, `i32`, `i64`, `usize`, `u8`, `u16`, `u32`, `u64`). This clearly won’t work, because the integral types don’t implement addition of lesser types—the default value for `RHS` of `Self` (that is, where `T: Add` means `T: Add<Self>`) is all you can count on, but `1` cannot be of type `T`.

The solution is to use a generic function that produces the value *1*. There is one unstable in [`std::num::One`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/num/trait.One.html#tymethod.one), and a stable one in the `num` crate from crates.io, `num::One`. Using the former requires the Rust nightly, using the latter requires dropping the `std::`, adding an `extern crate num;` and adding `num` to your Cargo.toml dependencies section.

We also need a `Copy` bound to allow the `*x` of `*x + 1` to work.

[Here’s the final result:](http://is.gd/3HK79e)

```rust
#![feature(zero_one)]

use std::ops::Add;
use std::num::One;

fn inc<T: Copy + One + Add<T, Output = T>>(x: &mut T) {
    *x = *x + T::one(); 
}

fn main() {
    let mut x: i32 = 10;
    let mut y: u8 = 1;
    inc(&mut x);
    inc(&mut y);
    println!("{} {}", x, y);
}
```

Comment: The only non-redundant part of my answer is a link to [the RFC that would allow implementing the operator assignment methods](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/953).